# Real network graph data [longitude, latitude, distance] from Open Street Maps

Tags: openstreetmap

I have created several algorithms to solve the shortest path problem. I am looking for real data with longitude and latitude coordinates as well as distance for nodes of various cities.

For example here is a [dataset](http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/challenge9/download.shtml) I found, however it is probably not very compatible with Open Street Maps or perhaps be a bit outdated. For example some nodes seem to be random houses in the middle of nowhere. The nodes are always named from 0 to N. It contains information about Driving times between nodes, Walking times, and then the Latitude and Longitude of every single node. And that is done for several cities. One file even contains the whole USA graph.

I am looking for something like this, that is more supported from Open Street Maps. Is there something similar in perhaps **raw text** format ? It would be ideal for my use case.

Comment: Why not create the network from OSM - or what is the question? See for several implementations here http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing where you could try your own algorithms

Comment: @Karussell I need offline graph data with latitude, longtitude and distance. That link seems to be filled with code and algorithms already made. Which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: OSM is offline data and e.g. in GraphHopper you can easily replace existing algorithms (note: I'm the author)